# How do i process objects from 2 lists interchangeably

Tags: python, opencv, file-manager

I'm using opencv and python to process images, however I'm stuck with an issue, I can't seem to process the 2 lists in which i store color images and their corresponding masks interchangeably, for the sake of this question i simplified the code to only show the images and not process them. Once i run it, the first color image is shown once, and all the masks are iterated, then the second color image appears and again, the masks iterate. I would like for them to appear as sets of 2 (1 color and 1 mask at the same time), then, when a button is pressed, the second set of images from list 1 & 2 appear.. and so on.

```
mypath = os.path.join('c:\\trainstcolor')
mypath2 = os.path.join('c:\\trainst')

images = list()
images2 = list()

for item in os.listdir(mypath):
   image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(mypath,item))
   images.append(image)
   small = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(small, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   cv2.imshow('hsv',hsv)
   cv2.waitKey(0)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   for item2 in os.listdir(mypath2):
     image2 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(mypath2, item2))
     images2.append(image2)
     small2 = cv2.resize(image2, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
     imgray = cv2.cvtColor(small2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     cv2.imshow('hsv2',imgray)
     cv2.waitKey(0)
     cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. A simple way is to make two lists and pop off the elements in a while loop. Also it allows you to check that they are the same length--and if I understand you correctly you would like them to be.

```
...
color_list = os.listdir(mypath)
mask_list = os.listdir(mypath2)

assert len(color_list) == len(mask_list)

while color_list:
    color_item = color_list.pop(0)
    mask_item = mask_list.pop(0)
    color_image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(mypath, color_item))
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much, simple and effective :)